# YUI Selector with an id that is a long number

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, yui

I have two divs. One has an id that is a string representation of a long number. The other is a shorter string. If I use the YUI selector to query for these divs, it fails to find the one that has the long number as it's id.

[Here's the jsfiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/septerr/Xkyfq/4/)

Why does it not find the first div?

Comment: Thanks.  SO automatically turned my "trivial answer" into a comment, and that was the result.  Deleted.

Comment: @Tim S. Van Haren: I hate that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Id can't start with a number, that's all.

Change from:

```
<div id='13367716691470000' style='display:none;'>test</div>
```

To:

```
<div id='foo13367716691470000' style='display:none;'>test</div>
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/gdoron/Xkyfq/5/)

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

[**source**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-id)